# Can I write non-unicode datatypes to Excel?

Tags: c#, sql, excel, ssis

I have an ssis package that creates an excel file from a sql server query. Problem is, I can't get anything other than DT_WSTR datatypes to work, even in advanced source and destination editors and data conversion element. It is my current understanding that Excel will only accept unicode strings as input. Is this true? Is there really no way to insert data and preserve the data types? Alternatively, can this be accomplished with a c# script task?

p.s. I have tried inserting a dummy column into the template file with the correct data types and dummy data, hoping the inserted rows would follow the data type of the row before it. That did not work.

Comment: Is your question whether you can have unicode and non-unicode strings written to Excel or is the question that you can't get say a whole number/integer to write to Excel?

Comment: I get a data conversion error in the excel destination task if I try to use anything other than unicode string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Casting a non-unicode string to Excel's required unicode is lossless.

If it's not already, just cast it (DT_WSTR, 255) along the way.  Adjust length accordingly.

Just about every data type can be casted to unicode DT_WSTR except dt_image and dt_text.

Unicode takes two bytes internally to store the same character.

You should see your non-unicode string just fine when you open the Excel file.

---

The excel driver will accept the following types:

> - Numeric - double-precision float (DT_R8)
> - Currency - currency (DT_CY)
> - Boolean - Boolean (DT_BOOL)
> - Date/time - datetime (DT_DATE)
> - String - Unicode string, length 255 (DT_WSTR)

Columns will need to be cast/converted to one of these type to make it through the driver.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/load-data-to-from-excel-with-ssis?view=sqlallproducts-allversions

[image: Cast/Convert]
[image: Derived Column]
[image: Data Conversion]

Comment: Data loss wasn't an issue in this case. I just wanted to preserve the data types so that the numeric/currency values could be be used in formulas and copy/pasted.

Comment: See updated answer for list of supported types and conversion available to satisfy the driver requirement.